# How to distinguish 1 optional parameter and 1st function name in Django

Tags: django, url

Following urls are valid:

```
//localhost/
//localhost/123
//localhost/hello/
//localhost/hello/456
```

url.py

```
url(r'^$', views1.custom1, name='custom1'),
url(r'^(?P<param1>.+)/$', views1.custom1, name='custom1'),
url(r'^hello/$’, views2.custom2, name='custom2’),
url(r'^hello/(?P<param2>.+)/$', views2.custom2, name='custom2’),
```

view1.py

```
def custom1(request, param1=''):
```

view2.py

```
def custom2(request, param2=''):
```

For url //localhost/hello/, custom1() function responds, with param1='hello' which is not correct!

Following 2 url can’t be distinguished.

```
url(r'^(?P<param1>.+)/$', views1.custom1, name='custom1'),
url(r'^hello/$’, views2.custom2, name='custom2’),
```

How to fix it?

Comment: If your param must be a number, try using `url(r'^(?P<param1>\d+)/$', views1.custom1, name='custom1'),`, this should only accept numbers in the regexp

Comment: try to change the url ordering. move url with `/hello/` before the `(?P<param1>.+)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Django docs for URLS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/), you'll see this:

> 3. Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

This means that on the first matching URL, Django will stop looking, and pass the request to the corresponding view. `localhost/hello/` is a valid pattern for the regex `'^(?P<param1>.+)/$'`

To fix this, simply reorder you `url_patterns` like this:

```
url(r'^$', views1.custom1, name='custom1'),
url(r'^hello/$’, views2.custom2, name='custom2’),
url(r'^hello/(?P<param2>.+)/$', views2.custom2, name='custom2’),
url(r'^(?P<param1>.+)/$', views1.custom1, name='custom1'),
```